# .htaccess: Redirect all pages to root of new domain, except in some cases

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I can use this to redirect all pages to the root of my new domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new.com/ [R=301,L]
```

However, I want to add a few more explicit redirect rules like this one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /something/(\d+)(\D*) https://www.newsite.net/foobar/$1
```

But the latter rule doesn't work any longer if I also put the code from above in. It doesn't matter if I put the `RedirectMatch` rule above or under the other code.

Answer (score 0):

Use only `RewriteRule` and keep specific redirects before generic one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^something/(\d+)(\D*) https://www.newsite.net/foobar/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.new.com/ [R=301,L]
```